# Compare the item from one list object with another item from another list object

Tags: c#, .net, linq

In below example there are two objects of product class. In each product object contains list of suppliers. Each objects can have one supplier as Favorite. If id of isFavorite suppliers from two objects are different than I have to maintain log in log file. But I am getting run time error.
Your help may appreciated.

c# code

```
namespace Article_Example
{
    class product
    {
        private int _productId;
        private string _productName;
        private string _productDesc;
        private List<Suppliers> _suppList;
        public product(int productId, string productName, string productDesc, List<Suppliers> lst)
        {
            _productId = productId;
            _productName = productName;
            _productDesc = productDesc;
            _suppList = new List<Suppliers>(lst);
        }
        public int productId { get { return _productId; } set { _productId = value; } }
        public string productName { get { return _productName; }set { _productName = value; } }
        public string productDesc { get { return _productDesc; } set { _productDesc = value; } }
        public List<Suppliers> suppList { get { return _suppList; } set { _suppList = value; } }

    }
    class Suppliers
    {
        private int _supplierId;
        private string _supplierName;
        private bool _isFavourate;
        public Suppliers(int supplierId, string supplierName, bool isFavourate)
        {
            _supplierId = supplierId;
            _supplierName = supplierName;
            _isFavourate = isFavourate;
        }
        public int suppliersId { get { return _supplierId; } set { _supplierId = value; } }
        public string suppliersName { get { return _supplierName; } set {_supplierName = value; } }
        public bool isFavourate { get { return _isFavourate; } set { _isFavourate = value; } }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Suppliers supp1 = new Suppliers(supplierId: 1, supplierName: "Supp1", isFavourate: true);
            Suppliers supp2 = new Suppliers(supplierId: 2, supplierName: "Supp2", isFavourate: false);
            Suppliers supp3 = new Suppliers(supplierId: 3, supplierName: "Supp3", isFavourate: false);
            Suppliers supp4 = new Suppliers(supplierId: 4, supplierName: "Supp4", isFavourate: false);

            List<Suppliers> lst1 = new List<Suppliers>();
            lst1.Add(supp1);
            lst1.Add(supp2);
            lst1.Add(supp3);
            lst1.Add(supp4);

            product product1 = new product(1, "Product 1", "Product Desc 1 ", lst1);


            Suppliers supp21 = new Suppliers(supplierId: 1, supplierName: "Supp1", isFavourate: false);
            Suppliers supp22 = new Suppliers(supplierId: 2, supplierName: "Supp2", isFavourate: false);
            Suppliers supp23 = new Suppliers(supplierId: 3, supplierName: "Supp3", isFavourate: true);
            Suppliers supp24 = new Suppliers(supplierId: 4, supplierName: "Supp4", isFavourate: false);

            List<Suppliers> lst2 = new List<Suppliers>();
            lst1.Add(supp21);
            lst1.Add(supp22);
            lst1.Add(supp23);
            lst1.Add(supp24);

            product product2 = new product(1, "Product 2", "Product Desc 2 ", lst2);

            int s1 = Convert.ToInt16(product1.suppList.Where(x => x.isFavourate == true));
            int s2 = Convert.ToInt16(product2.suppList.Where(x => x.isFavourate == true));
            if(!(s1.Equals(s2)))
            {
                string log = "Supplier " + s1 + " has changed to " + s2 + " !";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Below is the error:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type
'WhereListIterator`1[Article_Example.Suppliers]' to type 'System.IConvertible'.
   at System.Convert.ToInt16(Object value)
   at Article_Example.Program.Main(String[] args) in c:\users\admin\documents\vi
sual studio 2015\Projects\Article Example\Article Example\Program.cs:line 74
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Thanks,
Nandkumar Satpute

Comment: it seems  return value of  your expression product1.suppList.Where(x => x.isFavourate == true) is not of type integer.  that is causing InvalidCast Exception

Comment: Actually I have to make clone of main object and if user made any changes maintained the log and save the details.

Comment: product1.suppList.Where(x => x.isFavourate == true)  will return supplier list .. you need to use FirstOrDefault to get the Supplier Object and then select Id of Supplier. that would fix your issue

Comment: Yes I got the error reason, but how I can check the isFavourate suppliers is changed.

Comment: use this line  int s1 = Convert.ToInt16(product1.suppList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.isFavourate == true).supplierId); for s1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, It seems return value of your expression `product1.suppList.Where(x => x.isFavourate == true)` is not of type integer. that is causing InvalidCast Exception. Try below expression

```
int s1 = Convert.ToInt16(product1.suppList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.isFavourate == true).supplierId);
```

that would fix Invalid Cast Exception

Comment: most welcome. let me know if you encounter any other issue. may be include not null check as well to be on safe side.

Comment: can it be like below to handle null

int s1 = Convert.ToInt16(product1.suppList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.isFavourate == true)?.supplierId);

Comment: var favoriteSupplier = product1.suppList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.isFavourate == true); if(favoriteSupplier!=null) { int s1 = Convert.ToInt16(product1.suppList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.isFavourate == true).supplierId);}